# Writing text to a PLC with C++

Tags: c++, plc

I'm using a library from CodeSys to write variables to a PLC with a C++ program.

This is how I write a number to the PLC:

```
void PLCconnection::WriteVariable(int a_value, int a_listPosition)
{
    unsigned long ulStart;
    PlcSymbolDesc *pSymbols;
    unsigned long ulNumOfSymbols = 0;
    int iNumOfVars = 28;
    int i;
    char **ppszVars = new char*[iNumOfVars];

    for (i = 0; i < iNumOfVars; i++)
        ppszVars[i] = new char[255];

    long lResult = RESULT_FAILED;
    lResult = pPLCHandler->GetAllItems(&pSymbols, &ulNumOfSymbols);
    if (lResult == RESULT_OK)
    {

        strcpy(ppszVars[0], pSymbols[a_listPosition].pszName); //getting the variable name

        //ppszVar;
        /* Write variables value to check, if variables can be written */
        unsigned char **ppbyValues = new unsigned char*[2];
        ppbyValues[0] = (unsigned char *)new unsigned long;
        *(unsigned long *)ppbyValues[0] = a_value;

        ulStart = CAL_SysTimeGetMs();
        if (pPLCHandler->SyncWriteVarsToPlc(ppszVars, 1, ppbyValues) == RESULT_OK)
        {
            //writing succeeded
        }
        else
        {
            //writing failed
        }

        delete ppbyValues[0];
        delete[] ppbyValues;
    }
    else
    {
        // Couldn't retrieve symbols
    }
    for (i = 0; i < iNumOfVars; i++)
        delete[] ppszVars[i];
    delete[] ppszVars;

}
```

Now instead of giving `int a_value`, I want to send `string`instead.

How can I get this code work with a `string`?

Below you can find some information about the method `SyncWriteVarsToPLC`:

This method can be used to transfer a list of variable values to the PLC. The values are written directly to the PLC.

- ppszSymbols: List of pointers to variable names. These variables will be written one time to the PLC.
- ulNumOfSymbols: Number of variables in the list
- ppbyValues: List of pointers to the variables values which should be written to the PLC. Attention: Must match to the list of the specified variables!